# Simplify modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the expression $p - (b\bmod p)$ where p is a prime number and $b < p$. Can we simplify this expression? I find that $(p - 1)b\bmod p $ looks equivalent to $p - (b \bmod p)$. For example, $5 - (2 \bmod 5) = (5 - 1)2 \bmod 5 = 3$. If the above statment is correct, any hint on how to prove this?

Comment: Simpler: it's just $\,p-b\,$ when $\, 0\le b<p\,$ since then $\,(b\bmod p) = b.\ $

Comment: i.e.. $\bmod p\!:\, {-}b\equiv p-b\ $ when $\,0\le b < p\ $ (and both your exp's are $\equiv -b)\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the "mod p" you are using is equivalent to the % operator, ignoring the standard definition. In this case, you are correct, but with a lot of edge considerations. The clearest clarification is that b is positive and $b<p$. Given this, we know that:
$0<p - (b\%p) <p, 0<((p-1)b)\%p <p$ since $p-1, b \not\equiv 0 \mod p$. We also know $p - (b\%p) \equiv -b\%p \equiv -b \equiv bp-b \equiv ((p-1)b)\%p \mod p$, so they are equal.

In particular, removing the boundary to include all positive integers b requires that $\%$ be the strictly non-negative modulo operation and that p does not divide b.